# Property defined during render and error in passing variable

Tags: java, vue.js, graphql, nuxt.js

I'm working a static website fetching data from wordpress with [GraphQL extension](https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql)

**My code**

```
export default {
    asyncData({params, error}) {
        // We can return a Promise instead of calling the callback
        let slug = params.slug;
        //return axios.get('https://dev.lesdeuxvagues.com/api/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?slug='+slug)
        return axios({
            url: 'https://dev.lesdeuxvagues.com/api/graphql',
            method: 'post',
            data: {
                query: `
                    query {
                        postBy(slug:"$slug") {
                            content
                        }
                    }
                `
            }
            }).then((result) => {
            console.log(result.data)
        }); 
    }
}
```

**First problem :**

I got this error, probably because my axios query is not a promise..

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "content" is not defined on the
> instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
> reactive, either in the data option, or for class- based components,
> by initializing the property. See:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

**Second problem :**

I'm tring to pass the variable *$slug* to the query to get the right content, but it's not working. I tried to see on the GraphQL doc, but I didn't get how to do it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you show  the GraphQL's schema definition?

Comment: Sure : https://ibb.co/m9Snae

Comment: That's not the schema! That's you hitting the endpoint in the GraphiQL tool! 
But it does show success parsing the query ... 
What is exactly the error you are getting?

Comment: For my first problem, I explained the error.
For the second problem, I'm getting a _No resource could be found_ because I think i shoudn't put $slug in the query like this...